# Virtual "name" field?

Tags: keystonejs

I need to have the name field of a model be virtual, created by concatenating two real fields together. This name is just for display only. I've tried the virtual examples in the doc, no luck. Keystone 4 beta5.

```
var keystone = require('keystone')
    _ = require('underscore');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Foo Model
 * ==================
 */

var Foo = new keystone.List('Foo', {
        map: {name: 'fooname'},
        track: true
});

Foo.add({
        bar: { type: Types.Relationship, required: true, initial: true, label: 'Barref', ref: 'Bar', many: false },
        order: { type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, label: 'Order', options: _.range(1,100) },
        price: { type: Types.Money, format: '$0,0.00', label: 'Price', required: true, initial: true },
});

Foo.schema.virtual('fooname').get(function() {
        return this.bar+ ' ' + this.order;
});

Foo.defaultColumns = 'fooname, bar, order, price';
Foo.register();
```

When I use this model definition, I don't see the virtual name in the defaultcolumns list. I want to make a virtual name so lookups are easier when this model is used as a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a virtual to do this. Keystone allows you to track and recalculate a field every time the document is saved. You can enable those options in order to create a function which concatenates these two values for you (either synchronously or asynchronously, your choice.)

One other thing I noticed is that `bar` is a `Relationship`, which means you will need to populate that relationship prior to getting any useful information out of it. That also means your `value` function will have to be asynchronous, which is as simple as passing a callback function as an argument to that function. Keystone does the rest. If you don't need any information from this `bar`, and you only need the `_id` (which the model always has), you can do without the `keystone.list('Bar')` function that I included.

http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-watching

The `map` object also refers to an option on your model, so you'll need a `fooname` attribute on your model in any scenario, though it gets calculated dynamically.

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    _ = require('underscore');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Foo Model
 * ==================
 */

var Foo = new keystone.List('Foo', {
        map: {name: 'fooname'},
        track: true
});

Foo.add({
        fooname: { type: Types.Text, watch: true, value: function (cb) {
            // Use this if the "bar" that this document refers to has some information that is relevant to the naming of this document.
            keystone.list('Bar').model.findOne({_id: this.bar.toString()}).exec(function (err, result) {
                if (!err && result) {
                    // Result now has all the information of the current "bar"
                    // If you just need the _id of the "bar", and don't need any information from it, uncomment the code underneath the closure of the "keystone.list('Bar')" function.
                    return cb(this.bar.name + " " + this.order);
                }
            });
            // Use this if you don't need anything out of the "bar" that this document refers to, just its _id.
            // return cb(this.bar.toString() + " " + this.order);
        } },
        bar: { type: Types.Relationship, required: true, initial: true, label: 'Barref', ref: 'Bar', many: false },
        order: { type: Types.Select, required: true, initial: true, label: 'Order', options: _.range(1,100) },
        price: { type: Types.Money, format: '$0,0.00', label: 'Price', required: true, initial: true },
});

Foo.defaultColumns = 'fooname, bar, order, price';
Foo.register();
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide more information? What is currently working? How should it work?
Sample Code?

EDIT:

After creating the model `Foo`, you can access the Mongoose schema using the attribute `Foo.schema`. ([Keystone Concepts](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/))

This `schema` provides a `pre`-hook for all methods, which registered hooks. ([Mongoose API Schema#pre](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre))

One of those methods is `save`, which can be used like this:

```
Foo.schema.pre('save', function(next){
  console.log('pre-save');
  next();
});
```

Comment: Edited initial post to add code sample for model and more explanation. thx

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Foo.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.name = this.bar+ ' '+ this.order;
    next();
});
```

Comment: While this may solve the author's problem, code-only answers are of little help for actual learning. You might explain *why* this is the answer.